# add fixed class depend on class visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add `fixed` class to ul element depend on visibility of a class.But its not working.

[image]

### And jquery is

```
if(!$('.list-vertical-post-like').is(':visible')){
    $('.single-post-share').addClass('fixed');
}else{
    $('.single-post-share').removeClass('fixed');
}
```

Comment: are you calling this `if....` check everytime there is a change?

Comment: When are you calling the `if` statement? It won't just listen on its own.

Comment: Is there more than one `'.list-vertical-post-like'` element on the page? Because if so `.is(':visible')` will be true if at least one is visible.

Comment: @nnnnnn no there is only one thing like `.list-vertical-post-like`

Comment: @DanielH no change happens